# ImageMagick installed with brew wont find ghostscript

Tags: imagemagick, ghostscript, imagick

Have used brew to install imagemagick and ghostscript. However, when i try to use the php extension imagick i can't convert pdfs to jpgs.

When i do it in terminal with 'convert' there is no problem.

When i look at my delegates in imagemagick i can't seem to locate gs.

convert -list delegate produces this:

Path: /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.8-9/etc/ImageMagick-6/delegates.xml

### Delegate                Command

```
blender =>          "blender" -b "%i" -F PNG -o "%o""\n"convert" -concatenate "%o*.png" "%o"
    cdr =>          "uniconvertor" "%i" "%o.svg"; mv "%o.svg" "%o"
    cgm =>          "uniconvertor" "%i" "%o.svg"; mv "%o.svg" "%o"
dng:decode =>          "ufraw-batch" --silent --create-id=also --out-type=png --out-depth=16 "--output=%u.png" "%i"
    dot =>          "dot" -Tsvg "%i" -o "%o"
    dvi =>          "dvips" -q -o "%o" "%i"
    dxf =>          "uniconvertor" "%i" "%o.svg"; mv "%o.svg" "%o"
    eps<=>pdf       "gs" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 "-sDEVICE=pdfwrite" "-sOutputFile=%o" "-f%i"
    eps<=>ps        "gs" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=ps2write" "-sOutputFile=%o" "-f%i"
    fig =>          "uniconvertor" "%i" "%o.svg"; mv "%o.svg" "%o"
    hpg =>          "hp2xx" -q -m eps -f `basename "%o"` "%i";     mv -f `basename "%o"` "%o"
   hpgl =>          "hp2xx" -q -m eps -f `basename "%o"` "%i";     mv -f `basename "%o"` "%o"
    htm =>          "html2ps" -U -o "%o" "%i"
   html =>          "html2ps" -U -o "%o" "%i"
  https =>          "curl" -s -k -L -o "%o" "https:%M"
   ilbm =>          "ilbmtoppm" "%i" > "%o"
    jxr =>          "mv "%i" "%i.jxr"; "JxrDecApp" -i "%i.jxr" -o "%o.bmp" -c 0; mv "%i.jxr" "%i"; mv "%o.bmp" "%o"
    man =>          "groff" -man -Tps "%i" > "%o"
   miff<= show      "display" -delay 0 -window-group %[group] -title "%l " "ephemeral:%i"
mpeg:decode =>          "ffmpeg" -v -1 -i "%i" -vframes %S -vcodec pam -an -f rawvideo -y "%u.pam" 2> "%Z"
    pdf<=>ps        "gs" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=ps2write" "-sOutputFile=%o" "-f%i"
    pdf<=>eps       "gs" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=epswrite" "-sOutputFile=%o" "-f%i"
    plt =>          "echo" "set size 1.25,0.62; set terminal postscript portrait color solid; set output \'%o\'; load \'%i\'" > "%u";"gnuplot" "%u"
    png<= webp      "cwebp" -quiet -q %Q "%i" -o "%o"
    pnm<= ilbm      "ppmtoilbm" -24if "%i" > "%o"
    pnm<= jxr       "mv "%i" "%i.pnm"; "" -i "%i.pnm" -o "%o.jxr"; mv "%i.pnm" "%i"; mv "%o.jxr" "%o"
    pnm<= wdp       "mv "%i" "%i.pnm"; "" -i "%i.pnm" -o "%o.jxr"; mv "%i.pnm" "%i"; mv "%o.jxr" "%o"
    pov =>          "povray" "+i%i" -D0 "+o%o" +fn%q +w%w +h%h +a -q9 "-kfi%s" "-kff%n";"convert" -concatenate "%o*.png" "%o"
     ps<=>eps       "gs" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=epswrite" "-sOutputFile=%o" "-f%i"
     ps<=>pdf       "gs" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pdfwrite" "-sOutputFile=%o" "-f%i"
     ps<= print     "lpr "%i"
   rgba<= rle       "rawtorle" -o "%o" -v "%i"
   scan =>          "scanimage" -d "%i" > "%o"
  scanx =>          "scanimage" > "%o"
  shtml =>          "html2ps" -U -o "%o" "%i"
    sid =>          "mrsidgeodecode" -if sid -i "%i" -of tif -o "%o" > "%u"
    svg =>          "rsvg-convert" -o "%o" "%i"
   tiff<= launch    "gimp" "%i"
    txt<=>ps        "enscript" -o "%o" "%i"
    wdp =>          "mv "%i" "%i.jxr"; "JxrDecApp" -i "%i.jxr" -o "%o.pnm"; mv "%i.jxr" "%i"; mv "%o.pnm" "%o"
   webp =>          "dwebp" -pam "%i" -o "%o"
    wmf =>          "wmf2eps" -o "%o" "%i"
```

This tells me that "gs" is indeed in use for some kind of pdf converting, and may be the explanation to that it works in the terminal with convert.

Here is the part that i can't understand and that i need help with.

when i execute 'convert -list configure' i get the following result:

Path: /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.8-9/lib/ImageMagick//config-Q16/configure.xml

### Name Value

CC             clang

CFLAGS         -I/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.5.3_1/include/freetype2 -g -O2 -Wall -fexceptions -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16

CODER_PATH     /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.8-9/lib/ImageMagick/modules-Q16/coders

CONFIGURE      ./configure  '--disable-osx-universal-binary' '--prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.8-9' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--enable-shared' '--disable-static' '--without-pango' '--with-modules' '--disable-openmp' '--without-gslib' '--without-perl' '--with-gs-font-dir=/usr/local/share/ghostscript/fonts' '--without-x' '--with-freetype=yes' 'CC=clang' 'CXX=clang++'

CONFIGURE_PATH /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.8-9/etc/ImageMagick-6/

COPYRIGHT      Copyright (C) 1999-2014 ImageMagick Studio LLC

CPPFLAGS       -I/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.8-9/include/ImageMagick-6

CXX            clang++

CXXFLAGS       -g -O2 -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread

DEFS           -DHAVE_CONFIG_H

DELEGATES      bzlib mpeg freetype jng jpeg png xml zlib

DISTCHECK_CONFIG_FLAGS 'CC=clang' 'CXX=clang++' --disable-deprecated --with-quantum-depth=16 --with-umem=no --with-autotrace=no --with-gslib=no --with-fontpath= --with-gs-font-dir=/usr/local/share/ghostscript/fonts --with-gvc=no --with-mupdf=no --with-pango=no --with-rsvg=no --with-wmf=no --with-perl=no

DOCUMENTATION_PATH /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.8-9/share/doc/ImageMagick-6

EXEC-PREFIX    /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.8-9

EXECUTABLE_PATH /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.8-9/bin

FEATURES       DPC Modules

FILTER_PATH    /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.8-9/lib/ImageMagick/modules-Q16/filters

HOST           x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0

INCLUDE_PATH   /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.8-9/include/ImageMagick-6

LDFLAGS        -L/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.8-9/lib -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/lib

LIB_VERSION    0x688

LIB_VERSION_NUMBER 6,8,8,9

LIBRARY_PATH   /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.8-9/lib/ImageMagick

LIBS           -L/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.5.3_1/lib -lfreetype -lbz2 -lz -lltdl -lm

NAME           ImageMagick

PCFLAGS        -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16

PREFIX         /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.8-9

QuantumDepth   16

RELEASE_DATE   2014-03-23

SHARE_PATH     /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.8-9/share/ImageMagick-6

SHAREARCH_PATH /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.8-9/lib/ImageMagick/config-Q16

SVN_REVISION   15193

TARGET_CPU     x86_64

TARGET_OS      darwin13.1.0

TARGET_VENDOR  apple

VERSION        6.8.8

WEBSITE        http://www.imagemagick.org

Path: [built-in]

### Name           Value

FEATURES
NAME           ImageMagick
QuantumDepth   16

in the CONFIGURE line i can read --without-gslib even though i chose brew install --with-gslib. Also, gs doesn't show up as a delegate in convert -list configure even though it shows as an option in convert -list delegate.

I have tried uninstalling both ghostscript and imagemagick and installed ghostscript first and then imagemagick. Nothing changed. I can't seem to be able to install it with ghostscript.

Can anyone help me? I would appreciate that a lot!

Comment: What happens if you run gs with exec from inside PHP?

Comment: Looks like you may need to re-install IMagick PECL package with your brew path in the configuration script.

Comment: I will try reinstall pecl.

If i try to use exec(convert file.pdf file.jpg) nothing happends.

Comment: I didn't work, imagemagick still won't run gs im afraid.